# Swift : Enum 'cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers'

Tags: swift, enums

I get this Error in swift

> 'BlockColor' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible
>   initializers

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

let NumberOfColors: UInt32 = 6

enum BlockColor: Int, Printable {

case Blue = 0, Orange, Purple, Red, Teal, Yellow

var spriteName: String {
    switch self {
    case .Blue:
        return "blue"
    case .Orange:
        return "orange"
    case .Purple:
        return "purple"
    case .Red:
        return "red"
    case .Teal:
        return "teal"
    case .Yellow:
        return "yellow"
        }
}

var description: String {
    return self.spriteName
}

static func random() -> BlockColor {
    return BlockColor(rawValue:Int(arc4random_uniform(NumberOfColors)))!
}
}
```

I got an error in this line

```
 return BlockColor(rawValue:Int(arc4random_uniform(NumberOfColors)))!
```

I have review my code many times but I couldn't find where is the error

Comment: Strange. Your code compiles without errors in my Xcode 6.1.1 and Xcode 6.3 beta 2 projects.

Answer (score 9):

I got the same error. My mistake was that i didn't mention any return (Int) type for enum method ( enum BlockColor:**Int**). after initialization of Int return type. Its Works now.

Comment: Man do I love StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

problem solved :) it seem like the problem was with my Xcode 6.0. the code work fine in Xcode 6.2 beta.

Comment: A problem of Swift versions?